# Is there a way to hide the default screen of tab navigator from appearing in the bottom tab in react-native?

Tags: react-native

So in react-native what I want is a project UI like this:

Screen A contains (Tab B, Tab C, Tab D), and each tab navigates to its own screen.

each of screens B, C, D contains (Tab B, Tab C, Tab D) and they navigate back to screen A with another button.

I am not sure how to not let screen A appear in the bottom tab.

I am trying to do something like this:

```
    <BottomTab.Navigator
      initialRouteName="A"
      tabBarOptions={{ activeTintColor: Colors[colorScheme].tint }}>

      <BottomTab.Screen
        name="B"
        component={B}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => <TabBarIcon name="ios-code" color={color} />,
        }}
      />
      <BottomTab.Screen
        name="C"
        component={C}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => <TabBarIcon name="ios-code" color={color} />,
        }}
      />
      <BottomTab.Screen
        name="D"
        component={D}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => <TabBarIcon name="ios-code" color={color} />,
        }}
      />
    </BottomTab.Navigator>
```

but there is no way to display A in this way.

Comment: what ui framework?

Comment: @DanielA.White react-native